# Three.js Node TextureLoader not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, jsdom

I am using node with three.js to render objects server-side. I have my OBJLoader and MTLLoader working and I am simulating the DOM using MockBrowser. Whenever I print a screenshot of the model, I can see the model just fine BUT the texture has not loaded on it. The code I used works completely fine if I were using three.js in a browser and I can see the texture, but in node.js with the exact same code I can't see a texture. I printed out the texture's image object and all it returns is an empty image object. I'll give code if needed but I'm not sure what else to do.

I'm not getting any errors or anything, the texture will just not load onto the object.

Comment: I give up D:, so close but not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I narrowed it down to the fact that three.js assigns the texture's image src as a URL instead of a base64 value and since I'm using node-canvas that won't work. I just manually loaded the image myself using this:

```
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
var url = "URLHERE";

request(url, function(error, response, data) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var image = new Canvas.Image();
    image.src = data;

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(image);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: texture, overdraw: true});
  } else {
    response = 'error';
  }
});
```

And then I set the object's materials to that value. I'm still having issues loading multiple objects and textures due to the way js executes, but at least the textures load, just not on the right object sometimes. I'll figure it out though. Leaving this here for any one that may run into this issue.